# What is a better way to solve these triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Someone brought the following problem to me and I have yet to find a satisfactory solution. Could someone help out? Many thanks.

> Let the $\triangle ABC$ represent a hill on horizontal ground $BC,$ with a right angle at the peak $A.$ On the peak a vertical tower $AD$ is erected. If the $\angle ACB=35°,\,\angle ABD=52°$ and $BC=66m,$ find: (a) the length of the tower, (b) the angle of elevation of the top of the tower from $C,$ wrt the ground.

One could of course write down equations involving unknowns and try to solve. In fact that's the only thing I could dream up, using the cosine and sine rules to find two equations in two unknowns. However I think that's very farfetched as it leads to a discouraging system, which I can only carry through by enlisting the help of a CAS. However, this was something given to secondary school children as homework, so I expect it to have a nice, compact solution.

What am I missing? Who will kindly point the way? Again, thank you.

Comment: There is an error somewhere. Extend the line $AD$ to meet $BC$ at $E$. $\angle ABC=180^o-90^o-35^o=55^o$, so $\angle DBC>55^o$, so $\angle CBD=107^o>90^o$, which is impossible.

Comment: @almagest Thanks for the response. But why is it impossible for an angle of a triangle to be obtuse?

Comment: It isn't. But a triangle cannot have both a right angle and an obtuse angle, because then the angles would add up to more than $180^o$ (so you cannot have $\angle A$ a right angle and $\angle B$ obtuse)..

Comment: @almagest I think there's a misunderstanding. The right triangle has angles $35,55,90$ respectively in degrees. None of them is obtuse.

Comment: Ok, so put up a diagram.

Comment: @almagest Would have loved to. However, I believe I have given sufficient information enabling one to put down an accurate picture of the set up --- it's just a triangle within a triangle, with a common base, and their vertices joined by a vertical segment, etc.

Comment: One of the hill or tower is n't vertical wrt ground because $\angle ABD $ is 53 not $0$. It is unclear which one in question.

Comment: $B$ is on the ground.  $C$ is on the ground to the right of $D$.  $A$ and $D$ are both elevated but if you drop a perpendicular to the ground the coincide with the same point $M$ on the ground. $\angle BMA = \angle BMD = 90$ and $\angle MBA = \angle CBA = 55$.  So $55 < \angle CBD = \angle MBD < 90$ so $\angle ABD < 90-55=35$.  $\angle ABD = 52$ is impossible because $A,D,M$ are all to the right of $B$.

Comment: @rishi  It took me a *heck of time to figure this out but $BC$ is the level ground.  $A$ is a point above the ground between $B$ and $C$ with $\angle BAC = 90$.  But This requires that $55 < \angle CBD < 90$ so $\angle ABD = 52$ is impossible.

Comment: @Rishi Forget about hills and towers then. The point is, you have a right triangle with hypotenuse as base and right angle as vertex. On the vertex produce a vertical segment. Connect the other endpoint of the segment to the other two vertices of the right triangle, and the picture is complete. Any other clarification needed? :) Thanks.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your input, but why do you think the $\angle CBD$ should be acute? That is *not* specified in the problem.

Comment: Because if it were more than $90$ degrees you'd have crane you head up and look the other way to see it and that would mean it is to your left.  But D,A, and M are *all* to the *right*.  Draw a picture.  It's *obviously* impossible .  If you drop $DA$ so it intersects $BC$ and $M$ then $\angle BMA=90$ and $\angle BAM = 35$ and $\angle BAD = 145$ and $\angle ADB = 180 - (52+145)= - 17$.  That's impossible.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\angle DCA$ the is equal to $52$ .  That would make $\angle DCB = 87< 90$ which is possible.

Comment: "Thanks for your input, but why do you think the ∠CBD should be acute? That is not specified in the problem."  It's specific to the problem that $AD \perp BC$ and with $\angle A =90$ that means where $AD$ intersects $BC$ (call it $M$) is so that $M$ is between $B$ and $C$. And that makes it impossible for $\angle CBD$ to be anything but acute.

Comment: @almagest You may have been right initially. Sorry for not taking enough time to understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

What you describe is impossible. $\angle CBD = 107 > 90$ but as $A,D, $ and $C$ are all to the right of $B$, we must have $\angle CBD < 90$.

Alternatively if $AD$ intersects $BC$ at $M$ then $\angle DMB$ is a right triangle.  And $\triangle DMB$ is a right triangle with and obtuse angle $\angle MBD$ and $\angle BDM = \angle BDA = -17$.

Comment: Thank you very much for curing me of my blindness. Much appreciated. This settles it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay what does angle A is right angle mean , is angle BAC IS right angle ? If it's then it is very easy ,let hill is on point e somewhere on bc you can calculate height of hill since in right triangle AEC and AEB 
$$h cot c + h cot (90-c)=66$$
Once you got h , then you can calculate BE and Angle DBC. And height of tower.

But 52° is too much because this how angle DBE will be 52°+(90°-35°)=107° which is not possible is peak is at 90°.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I know but I am using this site first time on phone and I mistook. I don't know how to delete this ? Sorry again !